# Is it possible to use CSS zoom value based on vw units?

Tags: css

I'm making a responsive design and I would like that displays larger than `1920p` scale proportionally with the viewport width. That would be useful for any resolution above `1920p` (e.g. 4k, 8k, 16k and others between).

To make that work (partially) I had to create media queries for each resolution, but the layout breaks at some dimensions when user is not using the full display width for the browser window.

What I currently have is:

```
@media (min-width: 2880px) {
  body {
    zoom: 1.5;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 3840px) {
  body {
    zoom: 2;
  }
}
```

And what I would like to do is something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    zoom: calc(100vw / 1920);
  }
}
```

This would keep the layout static for any resolution above `1920p`.

Unfortunately, the `calc()` function parses the resulting value as `px` and the browser is ignoring the value because `zoom` property only accepts `number` or `percentage` on its value.

For example in a `3840p` resolution, I was expecting to have `2` but the actual output is `2px`.

Is there a way to somehow convert this output into a raw `number` without units?

---

I've created a fiddle to exemplify the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/bfaria/41rqxbs0/

In this fiddle, you can resize the output viewport to see how the zoom behaves for resolutions above 625px. Please note that if you inspect the `body` element you are going to see that the `zoom: calc(100% * calc(100vw / 625));` declaration has this warning: `Invalid property value`.

Comment: 2880 / 1920 = 1.5 and not 2. Where did you get 2 from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New Answer:

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom), CSS Zoom is:

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Therefore there *will* be issues. Zoom currently does not seem to accept `calc` values as options (exact reason is unclear, maybe multiple).

However, as stated on MDN:

> [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) should be used instead of this property, if possible. However, unlike CSS Transforms, zoom affects the layout size of the element.

So, you should be using `transform: scale();` instead of `zoom`. But transform scale only accepts a unitless number; 1 = 100% zoom level.

What you're trying to achieve can't be done in CSS3 with the approach you're currently looking at.

Therefore you would need to auto generate numbers in LESS CSS (see link below) or to auto generate values in Javascript. Finally, and the most time consuming would be to set all the contents of your page to scale based on `vw` and `vh` - so every length measurement above 1920px is set as a ***viewport width*** or a ***viewport height*** value.

## Options:

- 1) [Use CSS LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689176/3536236) (method 1 - numbers and percentage types)
- 2) [Use CSS LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978702/3536236) (method 2 - string interpolation)
- 3) [Use `Transform: scale()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css) **Recommended** and combine with other options here.
- 4) [Use Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094301/changing-page-scale-via-javascript) to update values once the DOM is loaded.
- 5) Set all values within your `body` to be percentage based above a certain media size, typically [using the `rem` length value](https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/).

  - a) Set all length values in your page above a certain media size to using `rem` [which will be dynamically adjusted](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/).
  - b) Use `calc` on the `html` element to set the size of a single `rem` unit. This will `scale` the contents. (please read [the link above](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/) for scaling font size to screen size)

    ```
    @media screen (min-width:1980px){
        :root { 
           font-size: calc( #{$min_font}px + (#{$max_font} - #{$min_font}) * ( (100vw - 1920px) / ( #{$max_width} - 1920) ));
          }
          .some-other-element {
              width: 4rem;
         }
      }
    ```

---

## Original (incorrect answer)

You should specify the length value of each value used in the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) that is [not a multiple or division number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732457/nested-calc-operations). Therefore the result of the calc will be, for example `0.22vw`.

I understand `calc` as using the length unit provided by the variables within the calc operation, so simply multiplying the result by 1 x the required length unit should convert any unitless or incorrectly-set length unit to the required value unit type.

`Zoom` [accepts percentages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) so you can force the resultant `vw` value of `calc(100vw / 1920);` as a percentage by doing:

```
zoom: calc(100% * calc(100vw / 1920));
```

Which will give you on a screen width 2500px:

```
100% * ( 2500px / 1920 ) = 130.2% Zoom value.
```

---

For your example of 2880px.

```
zoom: calc(100% * calc(2880px / 1920)); = 100% * 1.5 = 150% = 1.5
```

*I do not know how you calculated that the zoom should be 2 for these figures?*

Comment: That doesn't work.
Did you mean: `zoom: calc(100% * calc(100vw / 1920));`?
Even with that one above it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrunoAlvesdeFaria yes two calcs; please define "doesn't work". What result do you get?

Comment: I got a `Invalid property value` in CSS inspector. Even if used on other CSS property like `left`, this calculation won't work.

Comment: @BrunoAlvesdeFaria please can you show exactly what you used for zoom? Sounds like a syntax error

Comment: You can try and space the `)` apart, maybe `1920 ) );` (note the spaces)  helps. `Calc` is very fiddly with it's whitespacing.

Comment: I tried both `zoom: calc(100% * calc(100vw / 1920));` and `zoom: calc( 100% * calc(100vw / 1920) );`. I'm still getting the `Invalid property value` warning in the CSS inspector.

Comment: I've created a fiddle to exemplify the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/bfaria/41rqxbs0/

Comment: @BrunoAlvesdeFaria thanks. Do you have the LESS CSS manipulator by any chance?

Comment: I don't have it. Is there any way that it could help in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the update @Martin.
I'll replace the `zoom` declarations with `transform: scale()` and keep the current implementation.

Comment: If `transform: scale()` works in your case, I think that’s a better choice than `zoom` in terms of browser support and consistency across rendering engines.